# Adding a comparator to a class hierarchy, safely

Tags: c++, templates, reflection, comparator

I have what seems like a simple and common scenario, and I cannot figure out how to do it.

I have about 100 classes (some abstract, some mixins multiply-inherited) in a class hierarchy. All I want to do is find a simple way to compare objects in this hierarchy so that I can avoid duplicates in vectors of them.

That is, my goal is, to give a function `f` like `vector::unique` such that
`f(vector<Node*>)` removes duplicates from its argument.

The problem is that if I write 100 different comparators, then I don't have a way to check that I didn't actually miss a field in one of the comparators.

So how do I do this in C++?

More specifically, the root of the hierarchy is `Node`. Each subclass C of node has members of the one of the following types:

1. `N*`, where `N` is a subclass of `Node`;
2. `vector<N*>`, where `N` is a subclass of `Node`;
3. A class `V` with a prexisting `V::operator<` , where `V` is not a subclass of `Node`;
4. A `vector<V>` as above

For example, a typical class definition might be:

```
class N : public Node {
   public:
      vector<N*> children;
      vector<Node*> siblings;
      M* parent; //M is a subclass of Node
      Orientations vector<Orientation> ; // another class, with comparator
    };
```

I'm also not sure I can use default tuple comparator since that doesn't handle the vector members correctly.

Thus, I want a method, for each `N` in the class hierarchy, like

```
 bool N::operator<(const N& o)
```

that determines whether `this < o`. Given such a method, I could just use algorithm::sort and algorithm::unique to remove duplicates.

It is easy to say this in words. Just sort each class by its members lexicographically; compare pointers by what they point to; and compare vectors lexicographically.

So it's one sentence to describe and would be trivial in a language with reflection - but how to do it in C++?

Efficiency is irrelevant, I just want it to work without accidentally leaving out a field - now or in the future. I don't have a way to test, you see, if I leave out a field, which is why I don't want to do it manually (also a maintenance nightmare to write 100 different operator< for 100 different classes).

So how do C++ experts handle this kind of issue, which must arise whenever anyone has a class hierarchy whose objects they want to sort?

Comment: _"which must arise whenever anyone has a big class hierarchy"_ Real c++ experts avoid to have _big class hierarchies_.

Comment: Actually 100 classes isn't really big, I edited it. It derives from compiler with a class for each kind of language element, seems like the standard way to do it.

Comment: Do they have reasonable interfaces mixed in?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by reasonable interfaces. There are interface mixins with no members.